# Add custom cordova_plugins un IBM mobile first platform 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, hybrid, worklight-studio

I am facing the issue in adding custom plug-ins into cordova_plugins.js file. When i build the application the IBM worklight generates new one hence my addition are not there.

I have followed the instruction given here and able to attain partial solution 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

Since am using **encryptWebResources** as true. The article says from 7.1 we can do this. We are using **7.1.0.00.20160726-1659**

Answer (score 0):

> Since am using encryptWebResources as true. The article says from 7.1 we can do this. We are using 7.1.0.00.20160726-1659

This is not what the blog post is saying. In fact, it is saying the opposite - if you are using encryotedWebResources you **cannot** use this workaround.

What you can do is:

1. Create your own Cordova plug-in by following these tutorials: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/
2. Or create a standard Cordova application instead: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/